# Spring Boot load bean before Log4j2 initialization

Tags: spring, spring-boot, plugins, initialization, log4j2

Using these technologies...

- spring-boot-starter 2.7.0
- spring-boot-starter-data-jpa 2.7.0
- spring-boot-starter-log4j2 2.7.0

I am trying to load a @Service or @Component (whichever would work) before the log4j2-spring.xml file is loaded, but can't figure out how to make that order of events happen.

We have a database that stores our app's custom configurations.  We have a @Service which accesses that DB-based data using JpaRepository, @Entity, etc.

Some of our Log4j2 configuration depends on values stored on our DB configuration.  So we wrote a custom Log4j2 Lookup plugin that wants to use our @Autowired @Service to query the database.  This allows us to put placeholders in our log4j2 XML file like this:

```
<Kafka name="LogToKafka"
            topic="${spring:spring.profiles.active}-${ourprefix:${spring:ourapp.kafka.region}}-${ourprefix:${spring:ourapp.server.id}}">
```

In our application.properties file, we add UUIDs as property values and our @Service looks up configurations in our database using those.

```
spring.application.name=OurApp
ourapp.kafka.region=35a5792d-5218-44cd-87fa-052097c65b92
ourapp.server.id=9f58c5bb-e564-45d9-ae2a-0c1a082a8ac1
```

In our database, those UUIDs would evaluate to runtime values (used both by Log4J2 and by other components in our application) like "us-west" and "dev-server-10".

The problem is that our @Service is not instantiated when our Log4j2 Lookup plugin's method is called, so we cannot query the database this way.

Is there a way to ensure our @Service is instantiated before the Log4j2 initialization starts?

I've read through dozens of articles on Spring Boot events, contexts, listeners, etc., but still can't figure out the magic combination of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I've found through code-stepping that Log4j2 initialization starts before the Spring context is ready.  So, no beans available.  Sounds like I need to let it initialize and then RE-INITIALIZE it programmatically once the Spring context is ready.  Wish me luck...that could get messy :-)